# Clip (don't render) anything outside of a cube / box, like Godus

Tags: three.js

I've been trying to work out how to clip / not render anything that falls outside of a box, exactly like how Godus works (pictured below: notice the clipping at the back)…

[image]

Originally, I experimented with constructive solid geometry (CSG) to manually split and clip every object that falls on the box boundary. However, this is hugely computationally intensive and isn't feasible for a system where I want to be able to scroll around and have the clipped area update in realtime.

Is there a way to achieve this in a way that runs in realtime without modification of the objects, perhaps with shaders or something else? I'm new to shaders and still don't quite understand them enough to know how to implement this myself.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can the camera go outside of the box? If not, just put a big cube around the area you want and give its inside faces a material.

If the camera can go outside of the box (which would be weird, since you'd be able to see through the back of the meshes) one thing you might try is using vertex colors to make all faces outside of your box the same solid color as the background.